# Отправка логов от приложения разработчику

Tags: java, android, google-play

У меня есть такой вопрос.

Допустим я написал свое супер-приложение и разместил его в `Play Market`. Его скачали тысячи пользователей и пользуются им. Однако приложение разумеется не без греха и время от времени в нем случаются ошибки.

Чтобы понимать что за ошибки, что нужно патчить и как дальше поддерживать?

Я в обработчике каждого исключения выполняю отправку неких данных на специально созданную для этого почту. Представим также, что большое количество сообщений не будет большой проблемой для меня.

Данные которые я хочу получать исключительно технического характера, никакой слежки за пользователями, никакого воровства паролей и прочих безобразий. Только те данные, что мне нужны для понимания причин возникновения ошибки и ее исправления.

А теперь вопрос

Как это делать правильно, чтобы не возникло много вопросов от пользователей?

Чтобы `Google` не забанил мое приложение в своем магазине и вообще избежать подобных проблем.

Правильным ли будет такой вариант:

В настройках есть галка, которая позволяет отключить эту отправку, и по умолчанию эта возможность включена. С одной стороны не хотелось бы тех самых проблем и претензий, а с другой стороны не хотелось бы лишать себя возможности определять источники проблем .

Comment: Дампать debug data это хорошо, но по мне, лучше их или в файл, или в текст на экране класть, чтобы пользователь видел, что пытается отправить как багрепорт, и не волновался, что его персональные данные уплывут вместе с ним.

Comment: Ммм...а почему нельзя просто подключить rollbar или какой-нибудь fabric.io?

Comment: @Vesper мне  кажется что выдавать пользователю информацию из лога (стектрейс например0 во первых неправильно (ему эта информация неинтересна и не нужна) а во вторых не безопасно (информация об исключении может быть уязвимостью в умелых руках)

Comment: Часто трейсов из play market вполне достаточно

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно изобретать велосипед, используйтей [crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) от Fabric (от создалей Twitter)

Установка очень проста - все абсолютно бесплатно, регистрируетесь, устанавливаете плагин для среды разработки, он сам добавит в проект необходимый код (предварительно показав что он собирается добавить).

Далее при краше будет отправлено информация о девайсе и стектрейс ошибки, и прийдет уведомление вам на емейл.

Comment: это конечно хорошо но вопрос был немного не про это

Comment: @JuniorThree в `crashlytics` можно поставить галочку `Enable Privacy Prompt` и после краша будет отображаться "отправить отчет или нет?"

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще замечательный проект [acra](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) все бесплатное, интегрируется за пару минут.

Comment: Часть о том как именно `acra` отвечает на поставленный вопрос (забанит ли Гугл? что `acra` делает, чтобы пользователи не думали, что она приватные данные крадёт?) лучше прямо в ответе приводить без необходимость перехода по ссылке.

Comment: после того как пользователь словит exception, выводим ему диалог "Хотите ли отправить сообщение об ошибке?" И там уже в случае положительного ответа, либо по email либо http запросом на свой сервер шлете информацию. Я и тысячи людей используют и никого не банят. Так что интегрируйте и не переживайте.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - можно использовать [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).

Вы можете настроить свои [evets](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/events) и зашить в них информацию, которую хотите получать из приложения. К примеру в поле Label (String) можно зашить JSON или XML в виде строки. Все зависит от того, какие данные Вам нужны.

Кроме этого, сможете получить массу другой статистической информации о пользователях, ошибках, приложении и т.д. Все это можно синхронизировать с Google Developer Console. Данные собираются даже в оффлайн режиме (отправляются при первой возможности на сервер).

И можете не бояться бана - это библиотека от самого Google.

Comment: Я могу, к примеру, отслеживать на какие кнопки юзер нажимает ?